# warning: quick boot/snapshots not supported on this machine

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an error when running my app using android studio, but before that it was working okay until an update(Android API27), I have tried uninstalling it but nothing,the warning am getting is;

> Emulator:Warning:Quick Boot/Snapshot not supported on this machine.A
>   CPU + UG feature is currently needed. We will address this in a future
>   release.

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 13):

a friend just told me the solution, so please find it here!

The issues have to do with the specific device you're trying to emulate and the processor you have (**intel core 2 or older**)

**To solve it:**

1. Create a new emulator
2. Select the device you would like to emulate.
3. On the next page with the header **"System Image"** select the tab "other images"
4. Download and select an image that is listed as `armeabi-v7a` under the ABI column.

That image should run successfully with your processor.

That's the solution! Hope it helps :)

Comment: did not work - emulator just quit. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/57432976/398348

Answer (score 12):

The issue might be your CPU hardware. AVD Google API levels 21+ do not run well on CPUs that do not support [Extended Page Tables (EPT) and Unrestricted Guest (UG)](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/30#issuecomment-372544743), such as Core 2 Duo. Your best option is to try a system image with AVD Google API level <= 20 on those type of CPUs. You still will see the warning but the emulator will boot up.

**Update:**
I had further issues and it seems the only way to boot to a usable system image is to go with an armeabi-v7a version on Core 2 Duo chips.

Comment: +1 could you have a look at my question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1473361/cannot-enable-intel-vt-d-in-the-bios.  My PC is showing the behaviour you describe.

Comment: I did it, now android studio says "You should be using x86 virtual device, its 100x faster" and the emulator is very slow, I cant even make it work. Any update for this?

Comment: I am afraid not. The limitation is the CPU not supporting certain technologies for smooth virtualization.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I tried to update my HAXM on my windows-7 using this [resource file](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm) from the official site - software.intel.com. Also available from [the Intel HAXM github page](https://github.com/intel/haxm).

So as I said after updating my HAXM-Windows from version 6.1 to 7.1.0
my Emulator in Android Studio started to work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your Emulator Performance under Tools>ADK Manager to Software - GLES 2.0. This will work if your AVD isn’t among the ones with the playstore icon

Comment: In Android 3.3.2 it's:
"Hardware - GLES 2.0" or "Software - GLES 1.1"
No changes when i switch.

Answer (score 0):

see if intel virtualization technology is turn on in your bios. worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Hyper-V, so I created a new BCD entry to disable it and be able to install HAXM:

1. bcdedit /copy "{current}" /d "no Hyper-V"
2. bcdedit /set "{GUID}" hypervisorlaunchtype off

The message still appears, but the emulator is running with the latest API version and the x86 ABI.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my cpu is "Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M - 2.30GHz". to resolve it follow the steps:

1. check the virtualization in bios is Enabled (for intel CPU)
2. remove intel HAXM from "Add or Remove program" (if exist)
3. in SDK Manager -> SDK Tools check "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" and wait to download the program.
4. go to file explorer to "android SDK location"\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and then run "intelhaxm-android.exe"

Reference: [official intel video for HAXM](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/videos/setting-up-intel-haxm-on-windows.html)

Now go to AVD manager and create an emulator. then run the emulator. if it runs with problem and doesn't work properly (the same as me), as the android studio suggestion create an x86 emulator:

1. click on the "Create Virtual Device" then select a device and next
2. Select x86 Images Tab and select one of x86 (ABI) and download it then next
3. continue to finish and create the emulator.
4. run the emulator.

I hope it's useful.