# Cordova black screen cold boot

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I am trying to run "cordova emulate android" on the default hello cordova project, however when I run it I get an alert saying "cold boot: snapshot doesn't exist", and the emulator screen simply stays black. Here is the terminal output:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
47 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 46 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s): 
    /home/marc/Documents/Tests/cordova/hello/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=/home/marc/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
No emulator specified, defaulting to test
Waiting for emulator to start...
emulator: Requested console port 5584: Inferring adb port 5585.
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.ssse3 [bit 9]
emulator: WARNING: Not saving state: emulator hasn't finished booting.
```

How can I fix this?

P.S. I am using andorid api version 26 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759022/warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine/49991074#answer-49991074). Quickly: The issue might be your CPU hardware. Certain AVD Google API levels do not run well on CPUs that do not support certain features; in your case 'SSSE3'. Try an older AVD Google API level <= 20.

Comment: Downvote without comment? This is a legitimate answer for me and might be to some other people.

Comment: Adding a virtual device w/ Android 5.0 Lollipop (API level 21) in place of higher version (API level 29) helped in my case. Thanks!