# Android studio's emulator doesn't start

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

7:45 PM Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

7:45 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

7:45 PM Emulator: CPU acceleration status: Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

7:45 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199715/emulator-warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine)

Answer (score 2):

Couple things could be going on here. first off Im assuming you're not running it in some virtual environment so few things you could try

1. The issue might be your CPU hardware, if you have like a core 2 duo processor or something along the low lines like that then it probably does not support Extended Page Tables and Unrestricted guest(thats your EPT + UG error) try running on an API lower than 21 and see if it works you will still get warnings but it should work if that the case
2. if that isn't the case see if intel virtualization technology is turn on in your bios
3. try updating your HAXM(hardware accelerated execution manager) on your computer using resource file from the official site(software.intel.com) or whatever it is

or if you don't even have HAXM you can try installing it....

Installation of Intel HAXM consists of two steps. First, you need to download it using SDK manager. Then you need to run intelhaxm-android.exe to install Intel HAXM

also would help to know what kind of processor/cpu you have

Answer (score 0):

Found a few links for the warnings:

For the first warning: [Quick Boot not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759022/warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine)

For the others: [HAXM errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Answer (score 0):

Install HAXM from "...sdkroot/ extras / intel" folder .Open the file 'intelhaxm-android.exe'
from this folder.If you don't have it download it.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting back to 7.1 version of HAXM driver worked for me.

the rest are all warnings, so my Emulator showed up finally!!!
Thank you all for guiding.