# Cannot run app in emulator (Android Studio 3.4.2 on Windows 7)

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 3.4.2 on Windows 7, 64 bit, Intel Core 2 Duo

I created a virtual device with API 26, screen 800 x 1280 and cold boot, in order to run this [tablet-mode android tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-adaptive-layouts/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#3). It runs fine on my actual phone (hardware phone).
When I click 'Run' and select the tablet emulator, it does not run . on the AS toolbar, I see

[image]

I am surprised because I had selected **Cold Boot**.

I click OK but wait for a long time and then see

> "Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300 seconds waiting
>   for emulator to come online."

the emulator screen is black. In the event Log:

> 8/9/2019 10:02 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 10:02 AM  Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on
>   this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We
>   will address this in a future release.
>
> 10:02 AM  Gradle build finished in 4 s 285 ms

I tried this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53193001/398348) to use system image armeabi-v7a instead, but it did not work. I also tried installing system image x86_64 and x86 but the emulator would not even launch.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many suggestions methods. But might be due to old processor it didn't work for me.

Soln I preferred - it's not necessary that you should use only AVM by Android Studio. You can set your own Android smart phone as virtual device.

An alternative method is: you can connect your android smartphone via USB

- Turn ON Developer Mode in your Phone settings
  (- More Settings Developer Mode)
- See to it that USB-Debugging is turned ON.
- Print Hello World (in Android Studio / IntelliJ Idea / Other IDE) within few seconds an app will be directly open on your phone.

Hope it works !

This only method worked on my Pentium(R) Dual Core Desktop.

Note : Turn off Phone Internet when you turn on Developer Mode for safer side. Also see to it that your phone OS is matching or advanced with respect to OS selected for development.

Tip : This will work at normal speed without taking much time if you have 8Gb Ram on PC.

Comment: you mention "set your own Android smartphone as virtual device" - how do you do this please? I can only find how to set an emulator in AVD, or plug in my phone with USB cable. Sounds like you have a 3rd way? Thanks

Comment: Connect your android smartphone via USB

Turn ON Developer Mode in your Phone settings (- More Settings Developer Mode)
See to it that USB-Debugging is turned ON. Accept whatever prompts come up in your phone. By accepting , it will link to AVM in Android Studio.
Print Hello World (in Android Studio / IntelliJ Idea / Other IDE) within few seconds an app will be directly open on your phone. You can cross check if your device is connected and used for AVM purpose by checking the box "DEVICE SELECTED - (YOUR PHONE NAME)" next to run button (upper right half for 4.0.1 version). @AlexKerr