# How do I install the Visual Studio Tools for Xamarin preview?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to follow the instructions on this webpage: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/

I have reached step 2 and downloaded the zip file.  However, there is no executable.  How do I install this preview? Is the preview the same as this: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/ ?

**Update**

Following Rajesh Sonars answer, here is the error I get running inside Visual Studio 2019:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: App1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>App1 -> C:\Users\bert\Desktop\Xamarin2019\App1\App1\App1\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\App1.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: App1.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  App1.Android -> C:\Users\bert\Desktop\Xamarin2019\App1\App1\App1.Android\bin\Debug\App1.Android.dll
2>  No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
3>Starting deployment to my_device ...
3>Starting emulator my_device ...
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -no-boot-anim -avd my_device -prop monodroid.avdname=my_device
3>Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
3>
3>Please ensure Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is properly installed and usable.
3>CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
3>Emulator my_device cannot be started.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Update 2**

My processor is: Intel (R) Core i7 950 @ 3.07 GHz.  I have the following BIOS: P6X58D-E version 0502

I initially enabled the two settings in the BIOS:

```
advanced/cpu configuration/Intel(R) Virtualisation Tesc
advanced/chipset/intel vt-d configuration/intel vt-d
```

Is there anything else I need to enable.  I accessed my BIOS this morning to retrieve these settings (so I could update my question) and it appears the second one is disabled.  I definitely enabled it (I even took a photo at the time and checked the photo today).  I am going to try and enable it later.  I want to research what it is first though because I tend to experience BSOD when I change BIOS settings.

Comment: You can read this document about [Hyper-V & HAXM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows).

Answer (score 0):

On **Windows:**

To try out Xamarin Preview features, you need to install [Visual Studio Preview version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/installation/windows-preview) which can be install side by side of your stable/release Visual Studio.

On **Mac:** You can select preview update channel

[image]

**Observation :** 
If I try to launch emulator by running the app, I get following error and deployment get cancelled.

[image]

**But**, If I launch emulator explicitly from Tools > Android > Android Device Manager > Start, then it launches and I can deploy and test on it.

Comment: Thanks.  Does that mean if I want to use Hyper-V with Xamarin Forms then I have to install this?

Comment: Are you running VS2017 or 2019? If 2019, then probably you don't need to install preview. You just need to follow [3rd step](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/)  from this guide.

Comment: It looks like hyper-v is not enabled on your system. Here is guide to [enable Hyper-v on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v).

Comment: Docker runs perfectly.  Does that not mean hyperv is working properly? Thanks.

Comment: OK...that means Hyper-V is good. Have you followed this Note from this [guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/) `More recent versions of the emulator (27.2.8, 27.3.0, or later), require an emulator flag while the feature is in the preview. To do this, create or edit the file C:Users<your-username>.androidadvancedFeatures.ini and add the line “WindowsHypervisorPlatform = on”, or start the emulator from the command line with “-feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform”`

Comment: I tried creating a file called androidadvancedFeatures.ini and adding the line you suggested.  It made no difference.  This seems to suggest it is not necessary: https://curia.me/hyper-v-support-for-google-android-emulators/

Comment: I get the error contained in my OP update when I try to run the emulator from the command prompt.  Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Before I accept; I have come across this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759022/warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine.  Could this be the reason? API levels 21 or less seem to work ok.

Comment: I have an intel core i7 (2010).

Comment: I tried it...and got Docker and Android emulator running side by side on Windows 10. Used `Android 9.0 Intel x86 Atom System Image`. Which image are you using? But one thing is for sure, that Visual Studio version has nothing to do with it. BTW, that processor is little aged ;)

Comment: Try to launch emulator separately Tools -> Android -> Android Device Manager -> (Select emulator to launch) Start

Comment: I am using the same image as you.  Could you have a look at my second update?