# Emulator is not working to run my application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

> Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

I am using i3 processor with 2gb+4gb Ram and Windows 10, but I got this message when I run my app in my emulator.

I have tried different API level like API 23 and API 30 both. but still got this problem. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you search about the question on SO? Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759022/warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine)

Comment: i have already read all this article but still can't resolve my problem. i am using i3 processor with window 10 pro. i have also downloaded api level<=20 and still have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

EPT is needed means the current processor you are using doesn't support EPT.
In case you don't know what EPT is 'EPT (Extended Page Tables) is crucial for memory virtualization performance.

Comment: tell me something more about this. and how could we resolve this problem.