# Can't run my vscode project on android emulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio

Everytimes i'm trying to run "npm start" in my vscode i'm getting this error in metro bundler

"Error
02:07
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: No Android connected device found, and no emulators could be started automatically.
Please connect a device or create an emulator (https://docs.expo.io/workflow/android-studio-emulator).
Then follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options. If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory."

and in android studio's log i'm getting this error 
"Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release."

how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Because vscode doesn't stablish the conection between the device (emulator) and the ADB, you have to manually do it. You can follow this video to accomplish that [Youtube link video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbeez3RO5Fk)

Comment: hey Jason thanks for your reply but i'm getting this error while following that video "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Can you run `flutter doctor ` and show us the output? it can be a problem with the adb installation

Comment: This might give you an insight of possible issue! `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759022/warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine/53193001`